# After Effect - Apply effect on multiple layers

Tags: layers, adobe-after-effects

I'm trying to use the CC Burn Film effect in After Effect CC 2015 on two image layers, one on top of the other.

As the burn effect seems random, I can't get it to burn with **the same aspect** the two layers !

How could I achieve that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with any Adobe program, applying an effect to a layer is only going to affect that layer, not the layers below it.

You'll have to create a **pre-comp** of the two layers and then apply the effect to the pre-comp.

Select the two layers you want to combine into one composition

[image]

Right-click and select Pre-compose...

Click Ok

Your two layers are now combined into one composition

[image]

Apply your effect(s) to the Pre-comp

If you wish to edit the individual layers, double-click on the pre-comp and it will open inside the composition window, with your composed layers within.